# Error while running a midlet in Eclipse: no class found

Tags: eclipse, mobile, java-me, motorola

i am using [Eclipse pulsar for mobile developer](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/) and MOTODEV SDK and iDEN sdk for j2me (midp2.0).

Debuggin midlet in Eclipse gives an error: **No Class Found.**

Can anyone help me determine the source of this error?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.mtj.core 4 120 2010-08-05 04:26:53.009
!MESSAGE Couldn't connect to virtual machine
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Debugger launch time-out exceeded
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.waitForRemoteDebugger(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.createVirtualMachine(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.runInDebug(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorLaunchConfigDelegate.launch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: the cause of this error is that it cant find midlet class.try this one it may help you.right click project>runas>emulated javame midlet. not as emulated jar.